# AEM 6.3 HTL variable usage

Tags: aem

I've really new to AEM, and I'm struggling getting with a button component. It has a drop down asking for open type, so either new window or modal. Ideal the  gets target="_blank" or data-modal as part of the render.

Here's my dialog:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Button"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns"
        margin="{Boolean}false">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <label
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                        fieldLabel="Button label"
                        name="./label"/>
                    <linkTo
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathfield"
                        fieldLabel="Link to"
                        name="./linkTo"
                        rootPath="/content"
                        suffix=".html"/>
                    <cssClass
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                        fieldLabel="Css class(es)"
                        name="./cssClass"/>
                    <open
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                        fieldLabel="Open options"
                        fieldDescription="A new tab/window, or a modal"
                        name="./open">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <def
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="(default)"
                                value=""/>
                            <tab
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="New Tab/Window"
                                value="target='_blank'"/>
                            <modal
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="Modal Window"
                                value="data-xxx"/>

                        </items>
                    </open>
                    <secondary
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
                        checked="${not empty cqDesign.useSecondary ? cqDesign.useSecondary : false}"
                        fieldDescription="Use the secondary style for the button."
                        name="./useSecondary"
                        text="Use secondary style"
                        uncheckedValue="false"
                        value="{Boolean}true"/>                  
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

and here is my button.java

```html
package apps.bbcom_aem_project.components.content.button;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;

public class Button extends WCMUsePojo {

    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Button.class);

    public static final String PROP_LINK_TO = "linkTo";
    public static final String PROP_LABEL = "label";
    public static final String CSS_CLASS = "cssClass";
    public static final String OPEN = "open";

    private String linkTo;
    private String label;
    private String cssClass;
    private String open;
    

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        Resource resource = getResource();
        ValueMap properties = getProperties();
        linkTo = properties.get(PROP_LINK_TO, "#");
        label = properties.get(PROP_LABEL, "");
        cssClass = properties.get(CSS_CLASS, "");
        open = properties.get(OPEN, "");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(linkTo) && !"#".equals(linkTo)) {
            // is linkTO does not starts with http 
            if( !linkTo.startsWith("http") ) {
              linkTo = linkTo + ".html";
            }
        }
        log.debug("resource: {}", resource.getPath());
        log.debug("linkTo: {}", linkTo);
        log.debug("label: {}", label);
    }

    public String getLinkTo() {
        return linkTo;
    }
    
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getCssClass() {
        return cssClass;
    }
  
    public String getOpen() {
        return open;
    }  
  
}
```

At this point I have no errors, and a maven clean install gives no errors.

Here's my current button.html

```html
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design}"><small class="text-muted"><em>Button Component - Configure</em></small></div>
    
<a data-sly-use.button="Button" data-sly-test="${button.label != ''}" class="btn ${properties.useSecondary ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-primary'} ${button.cssClass}" href="${button.linkTo}" role="button" data-opentype="${button.open}" ${button.open} >${button.label} ${button.open}</a>
```

and when I inspect the element, I see this:

```html
<a class="btn btn-secondary " href="#" role="button" data-opentype="data-xxx" ${button.open}="">Workspaces data-xxx</a>
```

The **data-xxx** matches what I selected in the component options, but I can't get that to render in the opening  tag.

Comment: use full fledged class name as: `data-sly-use.button="apps.bbcom_aem_project.components.content.button.Button"`

Answer (score 1):

HTL (previously known as Sightly) uses HTML5 data attributes to define statements over blocks of markup.

This markup is missing the data attribute, so is not HTML5 compliant

```
<a ... ${button.open}></a>
```

You can use the **[data-sly-attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/block-statements.html#attribute)** statement to set the attribute but you required to pass a key-value pairs map object

```
<a ... data-sly-attribute="${button.open}"></a>
```

This will output

```
<a .... target="_blank"></a>
```

Also you should consider moving from WCMUsePojo to [Sling Models](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html) as is recommended by Adobe

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `<a ${button.open}=""></a>` would not work as it is not part of the HTL spec. If you want to render an attribute name AND value you must use:

```
 <a data-sly-attribute="${button.open}"></a>
```

Please note that `button.open` **must** be an object, preferably a map, for example

`{"data-xxx":""}`

This will render:

```
<a data-xxx=""></a>
```

please refer to the [data-sly-attribute spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#223-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```html
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design}"><small class="text-muted"><em>Button Component - Configure</em></small></div>

<sly data-sly-test="${properties.open == 'tab'}">
  <a data-sly-use.button="Button" data-sly-test="${button.label != ''}" class="btn ${properties.useSecondary ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-primary'} ${button.cssClass} tab" href="${button.linkTo}" role="button" target="_blank" >  ${button.label} ${button.open}  </a>
</sly>

<sly data-sly-test="${properties.open == 'modal'}">
  <a data-sly-use.button="Button" data-sly-test="${button.label != ''}" class="btn ${properties.useSecondary ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-primary'} ${button.cssClass} modal" href="${button.linkTo}" role="button" data-lity >  ${button.label} ${button.open}  </a>
</sly>


<sly data-sly-test="${!properties.open}">
  <a data-sly-use.button="Button" data-sly-test="${button.label != ''}" class="btn ${properties.useSecondary ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-primary'} ${button.cssClass}" href="${button.linkTo}" role="button" >  ${button.label} ${properties.open}  </a>
</sly>
```

It's not the cleanest, but as I only have two options, it seems to work.

Comment: I know. I can live with it as there are only two options, but if we need more, I'll pull in a more experiences AEM dev.